# Collective word for software and hardware

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a term that collectively describes both software and hardware. Doesn't have to be a single word but it would be preferable.

Comment: ***computer***?  ***computing device***?  Or if you're up for a neologism, and you primarily intend the word to be written, not spoken, then either ***everyware*** or ***anyware*** might be amusing.

Comment: In formal documents I suspect a term such as "computing system" would be used.

Comment: "computer or IT system"

Comment: A similar question was posted to StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288182/terminology-whats-a-word-that-conveys-software-firmware-and-hardware-co

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your context to a great extent, but common IT parlance would just refer to "a system". It would be unnecessary to prefix this with "computing", "IT" or similar if the context is clear, e.g. *we lost connectivity because the system was down*.

Comment: System is the most correct answer.  If we needed a hypernym specific to hardware and software, we might need to make a new term.  https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=computerware

Answer (score 1):

*Ecosystem*.  When used for technology, the word describes not just hardware and software within or related to a single device, but across multiple devices, services, or product lines.

For example, one could describe phones, tablets and other devices running the Android operating system, as well as the apps that run on those devices, and compatible accessories as constituting the 'Android ecosystem'.

Answer (score 0):

Going to go with technology as it encompasses everything about computers and gadgets in general.

Answer (score -1):

Computer. Edited: I suggest this because all functional computers comprise hardware and software.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage - Stack Exchange! Instead of padding out your answer with gibberish, it might be more helpful to explain why your answer is correct, give examples, or explain what contexts it does or doesn't work in. Please feel free to edit your answer if there's any more information you can share that might be helpful!